# Issue in using nil coalescing operator for incrementing a value

Tags: ios, swift

There is a function which checks the realm database for the max value and if there’s one, then it increments the max value by 1 and if there’s no max value then the value will be 0. This is given like so…

```
func chatMessageIncrementId() -> Int {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var id = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).map { $0.id }.max() ?? 0
    id = id + 1
    return id
}
```

But what I want to achieve is I don’t want the line id  = id + 1 and I want to merge it into this line `var id = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self)….` itself.

How can I achieve that…?

Comment: Hello. If you have a new question, please post it as a new question, do not modify existing ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply group the current value of `id` using parentheses and add `1` to it. Btw the `??` is not the ternary operator, but nil coalescing operator for `Optional`s.

```
let id = (realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).map { $0.id }.max() ?? 0) + 1
```

Comment: ok @Dávid Pásztor..I'll try...Also..thanks for the correction…:)